# How to get the model column value from the foreign key

Tags: django

I am trying to learn Django and I have a simple model like:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    labelled_image = models.ForeignKey(LabelModel, db_column='label')
```

So this refers to another model(`LabelModel`), which is defined as:

```
class LabelModel(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/label',
                             db_column='path', default='Some Value')
```

Now, at some point I save an instance of a `Document` model and I get hold of the primary key. So, I can get the model instance by:

```
obj = Document.objects.filter(pk=document_id)
```

Now, my question is how can I get the actual value of the corresponding `image` in the `LabelModel` that the foreign key points to? In database pseudocode I would have something like (I have not done this in a while):

```
SELECT path from label_table where id=obj.labelled_image
```

and this would return me the path string from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must use `get` not `filter` in your original query to get the Document:

```
obj = Document.objects.get(pk=document_id)
```

because `filter` always returns a queryset, even if there is only one matching object.

Now you have `obj`, you can just use the normal dot notation to get the attribute:

```
obj.labelled_image
```

This returns the relevant instance of LabelModel, and `obj.labelled_image.image` will return the value of the file field.

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. Also, thanks for the tip on not using `filter`